# matplotlib quiver: how to change the origin position, or invert the y-axis orientation?

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to change the orientation of the y axis in the quiver plot by matplotlib? As the equivalent of origin='upper' in plt.imshow.

I could not find the equivalent in the documentation, but maybe someone knows a trick to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the y-axis limits explicitly using `ax.set_ylim()`. If you use `ax.get_ylim()` to find the current limits, its a simple command to switch the minimum and maximum around:

```
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[1], ax.get_ylim()[0])
```